# After updating to Creators Update, the lock screen forgets my username

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1703

This is a new one on Windows for me:

After I upgraded my Windows 10 install to Creators Update, any time I sign out or lock the screen (Win+L), I have to enter not only my password, but also my username.

Before this update, this only happened after poweroffs and reboots (which also was  a bit weird to me).

Is this a Creators Update issue, or somehow related to a company wide IT policy? (I prefer not to ask them as they're useless).

Comment: Is the Windows domain-connected? If it is domain-connected, there may be a group policy enabled to do exactly this. I have the same update on my home PC and it does not do this.

Comment: As @Darius already said, it is most likely a Group Policy.  My team utilizes the same one:  `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options` and then enable `Interactive logon: Do not display last user name`.